# sap.m.Table factory function with the "this" view context

Tags: javascript, sapui5

how can I set the binding of the view into the factory function of the sap.m.Table?

The table is declared in this way:

```
<Table id="responsivetreetable" headerText="Collections" mode="SingleSelectMaster" 
items="{ path:'/', model:'CollectionTree', factory:'.collectionTreeFactory'}">
```

and in the controller I implemented the collectionTreeFactory function in this way:

```
collectionTreeFactory: function(id, context) {
```

inside the factory function, when I use the variable this, it refers to the factory context and not to the view context. How can I achieve this goal?
My first idea was to use the .bind(this) function, but I didn't found any documentation on how to do a factory function outside the xml view.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

Normally the factory function `this` is bound to the controller automatically. You can check out his fiddle (look into the console to see the `this` value): https://jsfiddle.net/93mx0yvt/33/.

Nevertheless, you can bind the table's items aggregation from within the controller and pass whatever function you want as a factory function. As you have said, then you can use the `.bind` function to explicitly set a value for the `this` context. You can find an example here: https://jsfiddle.net/93mx0yvt/34/.

The relevant code snippet is this:

```
oTable.bindItems({
    path: "/",
    model: "CollectionTree",
    factory: this.collectionTreeFactory.bind(this)
});
```

Check out the [bindAggregation documentation](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.base.ManagedObject.html#bindAggregation) for more details (`bindItems` is just a shorthand for `bindAggregation("items", ...)`).

Answer (score 0):

this.getView().getController() will give you the controller reference within the factory function.